# Azure Mobile App with ASP.Net backend posting data to a SQL Server table with a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, postman

I have an ASP.NET backend for an Azure mobile app. It has two tables one with a foreign key in the dataobjects folder.

```
public class Claim : EntityData
{
    public string CarReg { get; set; }
    public int StartMileage { get; set; }
    public int? EndMileage { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Petrol> Petrols { get; set; }
}

public class Petrol : EntityData
{
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public float Quantity { get; set; }
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public virtual Claim Claim { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
        new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention
 <TableColumnAttribute, string>("ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) =>
    attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
}
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Petrol> Petrols { get; set; }
```

The `Petrols` tables has created a column called `Claim_id` and I am able to add data to the `Petrols` table manually (using the id key for one of the existing claim rows).

But when I tried using JSON post calls (using postman), I am only able to post to the `Claim` table.

I cannot post to the `Petrol` table using a currently existing Claim id. 
Below is the syntax I am using.

```
{
    "station": "testpetrol",
    "cost": 100,
    "quantity": 99,
    "date": "2017-07-26T00:00:00Z",
    "mileage": 100,
    "claim": {
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-26T11:18:54.062Z",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-26T11:18:54.062Z",
        "version": "AAAAAAAAD8U=",
        "id": "6FFFC2B6-C410-4D5A-987B-DA0662F75F03",
        "user_id": "sid:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""submitted_date": null,
        "end_date": null,
        start_date": "2017-07-25T00: 00: 00Z",
            "end_mileage": null,
            "start_mileage": 15001,
                 "car_reg": "TestClaim"
                 }
    }
}
```

Above will post to  both the Petrols table and the Claims table if they Claim Id is not already in use, but if the Claim already exists (it gives me a violation of primary key contract error on the Claims table ). 
What I want to do is post the Petrols table that is related to a Claim table by the foreign key Claim_Id field in the Petrols table. I come from an Asp.net webforms/ SQL background where adding new data with a foreign key is easy. This is my first real go of using Entity framework and I cannot see where I am going wrong. Have I created my objects correctly and related them correctly, or am I using Postman incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Above will post to both the Petrols table and the Claims table if they Claim Id is not already in use, but if the Claim already exists (it gives me a violation of primary key contract error on the Claims table ).

AFAIK, if you specific the `claim` property within the `Petrol` object and send request against Petrol table, then it would add the new claim record and add the new Petrol record. If the value of `claim.id` has existed in Claim table, then you would retrieve the error as follows:

[image]

If you want to add a new record to Petrol table with a existing `Claim_id`, you could modify the `Petrol` model and define the foreign key property as follows:

```
public class Petrol : EntityData
{
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public float Quantity { get; set; }
    public Decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Station { get; set; }

    public string Claim_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Claim_Id")]
    public virtual Claim Claim { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried decorating with the foreign key but I had done it on the string Client_id not the Client Client object. Perfect thank you.